# How to rewrite an url with two query inside to one folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm facing a problem to transform my actual url

http://website.com/login/profil.php?id=34&pseudo=robin

into this one :

http://website.com/myspace

I checked if the rewrite engine works well and it's ok so that's my .htaccess

```html
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&pseudo=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^myspace\$  http://website/login/profil.php?id=$1&pseudo=$2  [R=301,L]
```

So my wish is to redirect the user's space on one common directory. what's the best way do do this ? am i wrong with the query ?

Thanks in advance guys !

This code doesn't work :

```html
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test\.html$ /profil.php?id=([0-9]+)&pseudo=([a-z]+) [L]
```

Comment: you want to redirect 
http://website.com/login/profil.php?id=34&pseudo=robin to 
http://website.com/space or vice versa?

Comment: yes i do in this sens

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess it will work only when get parameters are in the same order i.e.

> id=32&pseudo=code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/login/profil\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} &pseudo=(\w+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^login/profil\.php$ /myspace? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: nothing happened with your code, i put the file into root! after i tried to modify your code to put htaccess into login path nothing happened too... anyway thanks

Comment: may be htacess is not enabled in your current server configuration.

Comment: try doing simple redirect to check if mod_rewrite is enabled or not

Comment: yes it's enable i'v already tried a simple Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test\.html$ /index.php [L] and i can go to website/test.html

Answer (score 0):

This format works for me. You also try this:

Put this line into your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^myspace/?$ login/profil.php?id=34&pseudo=robin
```

And yes, do not forget to set rewrite base in your .htaccess file:
below line will set the base url:

```
RewriteBase /
```

So, basically you need to put these both lines into your htaccess file

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^myspace/?$ login/profil.php?id=34&pseudo=robin
```

For dynamic id and name, you can use:

```
RewriteRule ^myspace/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9._-]+)/?$ login/profil.php?id=$1&pseudo=$2
```

So, into your profile.php file, you can check parameter values(id and name)by

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

So, example, you will have to run the url something like,

http://websitename.com/myspace/20/robin/ or
http://websitename.com/myspace/25/john/ ... and like wise.

Comment: yeah it works for me like that but i need to adapt for all users !

Comment: Data can be passed through either get method or post method, i do not know your functional working into your site but if you pass the id and username through form,

Comment: e.g. <form action="http://websitename.com/myspace" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="id"><input type="hidden" name="username"></form>, so when you will submit this form then only it will pass your data into hidden format,

Comment: otherwise you must have to pass data through get method as mentioned above. But i think if you are stick to hide data in url, then why you are not passing encrypted format data into above url /myspace/{id}/{name}/ and decrypt into your profile.php file

Comment: yeah i use a form post method to send data and transit by url my wish is to give less information when data are sent